# I am facing an issue while I was trying to take backup of a database

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the below error while I was trying to take backup on one of our server. Can someone help me on this.

> 10 percent processed.
>   20 percent processed.
>   30 percent processed.
>   40 percent processed.
>   50 percent processed.
>   60 percent processed.
>   70 percent processed.
>   80 percent processed.
>   90 percent processed.
>
> Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Read on "E:\Program Files\SQl Server 2008\MSSQL10_50.GP\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase.mdf" failed: 38 (Reached the end of the file.)
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Er, why was this closed?  The linked duplicate is about a `RESTORE DATABASE` failing.  This is about `BACKUP DATABASE` failing.  A backup of an online database shouldn't fail for this reason.  It shouldn't even be *online* if it's a truncated database file.  OP:  Take a look at the SQL Server error logs, and search online for "BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."  The other option off the top of my head is a damaged disk.

Comment: Another possibility [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77322/backups-failing-for-all-databases).  Hard to say if it's relevant, however.